# How to install AutoHotkey in Ubuntu?

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts, keys

I used Auto Hotkey software to make Shortcut keys that activates most of wanted things. And i would like to do something like that in ubuntu too. so my question is that How to install Autohotkey? Or is there an alternative for ubuntu?How to use it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Autokey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/downloads/list). You can find it in the Ubuntu Software Centre.

Comment: Is Autohotkey officially available for Ubuntu?

Comment: I've searched it in Ubuntu software center. But it says no results found. i've searched so many similar keywords but nothing that I want. I want to make shortcut keys just as I can do in Windows, in autohotkey software.
`http://www.autohotkey.com/`
And also I just want something like that. Alternatives are also enough. But it should have the qualities of Autohotkey

Comment: Yes , it is there in Software center.
Also you can download it from here https://code.google.com/p/autokey/downloads/list

Comment: The Ubuntu source package is [`autokey`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/autokey) which contains the binary packages `autokey-gtk`, `autokey-qt` and `autokey-common`. To install it in Ubuntu you want to run `sudo apt install autokey-gtk` or `sudo apt install autokey-qt`. `autokey-qt` is only available up to and including Ubuntu 16.04, after that only `autokey-gtk` is available.

Comment: The packages `autohotkey-gtk` and `autohotkey-qt` do not exist in the Ubuntu repositories (in Ubuntu 23.04) and do not exist in the Snap store.

Comment: The linked project is out of date. The latest release is from 2012.